Doubt with isometries and injectivity Radius
I had a doubt as I was attempting to prove the following theorem:

Suppose $(M,g)$ and $(\tilde{M},\tilde{g})$ are connected manifolds with $\tilde{M}$ complete, and $\pi:\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$ is a local isometry. Then $M$ is complete and $\pi$ is a covering map.

Let $p\in M$, let $B_{\epsilon}(p)$ be a geodesic ball, and let $B$ be an indexing set of $\pi^{-1}(p)$. For each $\beta\in B$, set $U_\beta=B_{\epsilon}(p_\beta)$ (the metric ball). To show that that the $U_\beta$s are pairwise disjoint, what I show that is for distinct points $x,y\in \pi^{-1}(p)$, $d(x,y)\geq 2\epsilon$.
But if $\operatorname{inj}(p)=+\infty$, doesn't this imply that for all $\epsilon>0$ and all $x,y\in \pi^{-1}(p)$ distinct, $d(x,y)\geq 2\epsilon$? Wouldn't that imply that the fiber is just a singleton? And then, once the theorem's been proved, you get that the fibers of all points are equipotent, and that gives you that $\pi$ is injective. So $\pi$ must be an isometry. From this, you get that if $\pi:\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$ is a local isometry, with $\tilde{M}$ complete and $M$ with infinite injectivity radius at a point, then $\pi$ must be an isometry. Is this true or is there a major mistake with my proof?

I suggest you read the standard proof using path-lifting property. Yoy can find it for instance in Kobayashi-Nomizu.
